# searching database and displaying on .cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, search

I have this code in my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Search(String searchstring)
    {

        var number = from n in db.UCountInfoes
                     select n;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchstring))
        {
            number = number.Where(i => i.IDNumber.Equals(searchstring));
        }
        return View(number);
    }
```

and on my `.cshtml` page i have this which i use to search:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" name="SearchButton" value="Search" class="btn btn-inverse" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

After clicking the search button i want to return the records found on another `.cshtml` page.

Answer (score 0):

```
  return RedirectToAction("Action Name", "Your Controller Name", number);
```

Instead of return View you can use the above method.
Here Action Name is the View Name you want to show the results into.